# Change old WPF ProgressBar controltemplate to WPF4

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I want a thermometer in my WPF app and found a template in [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/magazine/cc163497%28en-us%29.aspx)

---

*Edit start*

I have found the reason why it doesn't work: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571674/issue-with-vertical-progress-bar-on-4-0-framework

But I/you? still have to figure out how to make it work with WPF4.

*Edit end*

---

The control looks fine, but it doesn't seem to update the indicator when setting Value.

I've pasted it into Kaxaml and also tried VS2010. Is the code buggy or am I doing something wrong with it?

```
<!-- ================================================
      ThermometerProgressBar.xaml by Charles Petzold
     ================================================ -->
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Page.Resources>

        <!-- Define template for thermometer progress bar -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="templateThermometer"
                         TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">

            <!-- Define two brushes for the thermometer liquid -->
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="brushStem"
                                     StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 0">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Pink" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Red" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="brushBowl"
                                     GradientOrigin="0.3 0.3">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Pink" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Red" />                        
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>

            <!-- Two-row Grid divides thermometer into stem and bowl -->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!-- Second grid divides stem area in three columns -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- This border displays the stem -->
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" 
                            BorderThickness="3 3 3 0"
                            CornerRadius="6 6 0 0" >

                        <!-- Track and Indicator elements -->
                        <Decorator Name="PART_Track">
                            <Border Name="PART_Indicator"
                                    CornerRadius="6 6 0 0"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Background="{StaticResource brushStem}" />
                        </Decorator>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

                <!-- The bowl outline goes in the main Grid second row -->
                <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                         Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                         Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                         Stroke="SteelBlue" StrokeThickness="3" />

                <!-- Another grid goes in the same cell -->
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- This is to close up the gap between bowl and stem -->
                    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderBrush="SteelBlue"
                            BorderThickness="3 0 3 0"
                            Background="{StaticResource brushStem}" />
                </Grid>

                <!-- Another ellipse to fill up the bowl -->
                <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                         Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                         Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                         Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="6"
                         Fill="{StaticResource brushBowl}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>

        <!-- Create Thermometer ProgressBar -->
        <ProgressBar Template="{StaticResource templateThermometer}" 
                     Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
                     Width="50" Height="350" Margin="50" 
                     Value="{Binding ElementName=scroll, Path=Value}" />

        <!-- ScrollBar to simulate progress -->
        <ScrollBar Name="scroll" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                   Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
                   SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10" 
                   Margin="50 0 50 0" />

        <TextBlock Text="Manipulate ScrollBar to test ProgressBar"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Comment: how did you bind the Value property ?

Comment: Do you mean this? Value="{Binding ElementName=scroll, Path=Value}" from the bottom of the inserted code

Comment: for me it is working. if i change the scrollbar. I have done the sample with Windows Forms

Comment: @Karsten Yep I mean that, ensure the binding is correct

Comment: I don't follow you. Is the binding wrong? Either way I tried to set Value directly

Comment: I copied your xaml to an UserControl and it works without changing anything but Page to UserControl. Maybe that helps you to find a solution.

Comment: As a page your code is working as well for me. There seems to be another issue outside the page.

Comment: It also works when scrolling the scrollbar at the bottom? I mean you can see the temperature indicator going up and down?

Answer (score 1):

i found out that you need to add a template trigger to trigger when the orientation Property is set "Vertical" . The code i made some changes, and works fine.

```
<!-- Define template for thermometer progress bar -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ThermometerProgressBarStyle"
                     TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">

    <!-- Define two brushes for the thermometer liquid -->
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="brushStem"
                                 StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="1 0">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Pink" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Red" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="brushStemVertical"
                                 StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Red" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Pink" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Red" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="brushBowl"
                                 GradientOrigin="0.3 0.3">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Pink" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Red" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

    <!-- Two-row Grid divides thermometer into stem and bowl -->
    <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Second grid divides stem area in three columns -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ShowGridLines="false">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- This border displays the stem -->
                <!-- Track and Indicator elements -->

            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" 
                    BorderThickness="0 3 3 3"
                    CornerRadius="0 6 6 0"
                           Name="border">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      Name="PART_Track" />
                        <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator"
                            Fill="{StaticResource brushStemVertical }"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
        </Grid>
        <!-- The bowl outline goes in the main Grid second row -->
        <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                     Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                     Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                     Stroke="SteelBlue" StrokeThickness="3" />
        <!-- Another grid goes in the same cell -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!-- This is to close up the gap between bowl and stem -->
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                        BorderBrush="SteelBlue"
                        BorderThickness="3 0 3 0"
                        Background="{StaticResource brushStem}" />
        </Grid>
        <!-- Another ellipse to fill up the bowl -->
        <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                     Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                     Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                     Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="6"
                     Fill="{StaticResource brushBowl}" />
    </Grid>

    <!--add Orientation trigger-->
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>    
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication44.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="518" Width="542">
<Window.Resources>
<!-- Define template for thermometer progress bar -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="templateThermometer"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">

    <!-- Define two brushes for the thermometer liquid -->
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="brushStem"
                             StartPoint="0 0"
                             EndPoint="1 0">
            <GradientStop Offset="0"
                          Color="Red" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.3"
                          Color="Pink" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1"
                          Color="Red" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="brushBowl"
                             GradientOrigin="0.3 0.3">
            <GradientStop Offset="0"
                          Color="Pink" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1"
                          Color="Red" />
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

    <!-- Two-row Grid divides thermometer into stem and bowl -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Second grid divides stem area in three columns -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- This border displays the stem -->
            <Border Grid.Column="1"
                    BorderBrush="SteelBlue"
                    BorderThickness="3 3 3 0"
                    CornerRadius="6 6 0 0">

                <!-- Track and Indicator elements -->
                <Decorator Name="PART_Track">
                    <Border Name="PART_Indicator"
                            CornerRadius="6 6 0 0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            Background="{StaticResource brushStem}" />
                </Decorator>
            </Border>
        </Grid>

        <!-- The bowl outline goes in the main Grid second row -->
        <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                 Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                 Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                 Stroke="SteelBlue"
                 StrokeThickness="3" />

        <!-- Another grid goes in the same cell -->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- This is to close up the gap between bowl and stem -->
            <Border Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    BorderBrush="SteelBlue"
                    BorderThickness="3 0 3 0"
                    Background="{StaticResource brushStem}" />
        </Grid>

        <!-- Another ellipse to fill up the bowl -->
        <Ellipse Grid.Row="1"
                 Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                 Height="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                 Stroke="Transparent"
                 StrokeThickness="6"
                 Fill="{StaticResource brushBowl}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>

    <!-- Create Thermometer ProgressBar -->
    <ProgressBar Template="{StaticResource templateThermometer}"
                 Orientation="Vertical"
                 Minimum="0"
                 Maximum="100"
                 Width="50"
                 Height="350"
                 Margin="50"
                 Value="{Binding ElementName=scroll, Path=Value}" />

    <!-- ScrollBar to simulate progress -->
    <ScrollBar Name="scroll"
               Orientation="Horizontal"
               Minimum="0"
               Maximum="100"
               Value="20"
               SmallChange="1"
               LargeChange="10"
               Margin="50 0 50 0" />

    <TextBlock Text="Manipulate ScrollBar to test ProgressBar"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
</StackPanel>
```